# How to create two or three level heirarchy of events in firebase analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am not sure if I am putting this question appropriately so please pardon me for that. When using google analytics in android projects ,there used to be separate methods for screen hits and events like

```
Tracker t = application.getTracker(Application.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
t.setScreenName(screenName);
t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

And for events something like

```
Tracker tracker = application.getTracker(Application.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory(ConstantParam.category).setAction(ConstantParam.action).setLabel(event).setValue(value).build())
```

So google analytics would differentiate between screen hits as just as name of screen and some event like api failure, where I can go 2 to 3 levels of hierarchy based on property. While using firebase analytics everything seems to be an event. So how to differentiate between screen hit and event and what do I need to do at coding level ?